# cakephp 2.6 passed params in Router not working

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Here is my code :

```
Router::connect('/edit_topic/:id', array('controller' => 'topics', 'action' => 'edit'),array('pass' => array('id'),'id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

The result with:

```
debug($this->request);
die();
```

is like that:

```
object(CakeRequest) {
params => array(
    'plugin' => null,
    'controller' => 'topics',
    'action' => 'edit',
    'named' => array(),
    'pass' => array(
        (int) 0 => '14'
    ),
    'id' => '14'
)
```

As you cant see we found id in two places,inside pass array, and also inside params array, tha's my problem.
I want to fix that,so that id appears only inside pass array

Comment: "that's my problem" - what problem/error/what does it cause?

Answer (score 3):

This is this expected behavior you can't change it. Any route element used (`:id` in your case) will be available under `CakeRequest::$params` property and since you have set it to "passed" it's also available under `params['pass']`.

Only option you have is to unset `params['id']` yourself in say controller's `beforeFilter()` callback. Though I don't really see why having it is a problem.